# Swift loop runs in reverse? Code conundrum

Tags: swift, loops, closures, skaction

I don't understand what is happening in this code...

```
fileprivate func genericNodeWalker(_ direction:Follow, encapsulatedMethod: @escaping (_ iNode:Int) -> Void) {
    switch direction {
    case .forwards:
        for nodeIndex in 0..<self.nodes.count {
            encapsulatedMethod(nodeIndex)
        }
    case .backwards:
        for indexNode in stride(from: self.nodes.count - 1, through: 0, by: -1) {
       // for nodeIndex in (0..<self.nodes.count).reversed() {
            print("indexNode \(indexNode)")
            encapsulatedMethod(indexNode)
        }
    }
}

fileprivate func fadeOutNodes2() {
    genericNodeWalker(.backwards) { index2D in
        let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: Double(index2D) * 2)
        let custom = SKAction.run {
            print("index2D \(index2D)")
        }
        let sequence = SKAction.sequence([wait,custom])
        self.nodes[index2D].run(sequence)
    }
}
```

I ask it to count backwards, which it does; but the code fadeOutNodes2 within the encapsulatedMethod runs forwards?

```
indexNode 6
indexNode 5
indexNode 4
indexNode 3
indexNode 2
indexNode 1
indexNode 0
index2D 0
index2D 1
index2D 2
index2D 3
index2D 4
index2D 5
index2D 6
```

Is there an obvious mistake here I cannot and I cannot see the wood for the trees? If I change the loop to run forwards, it also runs forwards.

How can I make it run backwards?

Comment: The callback for your genericNodeWalker is being called in reverse, but you are inserting a delay of 2 * index2D before your custom action will be executed. This means that the first call (for index2D = 6) will be delayed by 12 seconds, the next (index2D = 5) will be delayed by 10 seconds. And so on. Which means the prints inside the actions will appear to be reversed.

Comment: You should add an appropriate tag for `SKAction` to your question since the problem seems related to this type.

Comment: It sounds so obvious when you say it; THANKYOU!! A good exam question I dare say...

Comment: If this has been resolve then please remove the question.

Comment: @joakim-danielson I posted the answer for others to benefit? You think I should just delete it?

Comment: That's up to you (not my downvote), it's perfectly fine to do it. I do believe that the answer could do with a better explanation of what you did to fix the issue besides a link to a comment.

Comment: I'll leave it for a day or two; if it collects any more down votes I will delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do, but a better API for your `genericNodeWalker` might be something like this (I'm assuming `nodes` is an array of `SKNode`, change the type if required):

```
fileprivate func genericNodeWalker(_ direction:Follow, encapsulatedMethod: (_ index: Int, _ node: SKNode) -> Void) {
    switch direction {
    case .forwards:
        nodes.enumerated().forEach(encapsulatedMethod)
    case .backwards:
        nodes.reversed().enumerated().forEach(encapsulatedMethod)
    }
}


fileprivate func fadeOutNodes2() {
    genericNodeWalker(.backwards) { index, node  in
        let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: Double(index) * 2)
        let custom = SKAction.run {
            print("index \(index)")
        }
        let sequence = SKAction.sequence([wait,custom])
        node.run(sequence)
    }
}
```

The walker will just call the callback with the nodes in the order you ask for, and will always pass a zero-based increasing index with each call.

So, if you have nodes `a` through `c` then the walker will call `encapsulatedMethod` with `(0,a)`, `(1,b)`, `(2,c)` when interating forwards, and will call it with `(0,c)`, `(1,b)`, `(2,a)` when iterating backwards. The walker doesn't care what you do with the indexes. It doesn't care about delays. It just delivers the nodes to the callback method in the order you ask for and provides an index for each node that starts at 0.

This also means that the callback function itself is passed a `node` and doesn't need to find it in `self.nodes` based on an index. There's also no need to use `@escaping` as the callback closure does not escape. It will be called for each node before `genericNodeWalker` returns.

Maybe this is better, maybe not. But I think it is a cleaner API.